# Multiple loops with same Ref Cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am using **ref cursor** as OUT parameter in my **procedure**. It is returning only **one row with 150 columns**.

After that I want to use same cursor in multiple functions as **IN** parameter.But when i try to use it only first function works successfully.

In first function, I am passing **ref cursor** from above proc, dynamic column name, and taking that column value with OUT parameter. I am using loop in 1st function to take column value and not closing ref cursor here.

In second function, I am passing same **ref cursor** as **IN** parameter, columnname(**for update purpose**),and column value from first function. I am using loop here also. But that cursor doesn't go in loop here.

And my update statement inside loop doesn't works.I am not closing ref cursor anywhere but I don't know why it happens? Any idea that will be appreciable.

This all objects I have created in package and I am calling those in one transaction in sequence.

```
Function GetPersNameId ( pinClientId  person.client_id%type, 
                         pupNameId    person.nameid%type, 
                         pupRC in out pls_integer ) 
return boolean;

Function GetOrgnNameId ( pinClientId  organization.client_id%type, 
                         pupNameId    organization.client_id%type,  
                         pupRC in out pls_integer ) 
return boolean;

Function GetEitherNameId ( pinClientId  person.client_id%type, 
                           pupNameId    person.nameid%type, 
                           pupRC in out pls_integer ) 
return boolean;

Procedure ResolveNameId( pinStartIntfKey number,
                         pinEndIntfKey   number,
                         pupRC   in out  pls_integer);
```

Comment: I assume you are using `dbms_sql` for "ref cursors", since `pupRC` is `pls_integer` everywhere. Am I right ?

Answer (score 0):

A ref cursor is a "unidirectional collection" which must be reopened, again, if you want to read it again.

You have two options:

1. Reopen your ref cursor before each reading.
2. Fetch your ref cursor to a record/collection of records and pass the record/collection to your subsequent calls instead of passing the ref cursor there.